# выдаёт ошибку "array(4)"

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, phpmyadmin

При попытки отправить данные в базу выдает ошибку:
"array(4) { ["dateCL"]=> string(10) "2021-11-25" ["timeCL"]=> string(5) "01:09" ["name"]=> NULL ["tel"]=> string(7) "8465489" }".
****При этом в БД данные не приходят.****

**Код из index.php**

```
            <div class="record text-center mx-auto">
                    <p><input type="date" name="dateCL" id="dateCL" placeholder="ДАТА" class="text-center dateCL"></p>
                    <p><input type="time" name="timeCL" id="timeCL" placeholder="ВРЕМЯ" class="text-center timeCL"></p>
                    <p><input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="ВАШЕ ИМЯ" class="text-center name"></p>
                    <p><input type="tel" name="tel" id="tel" placeholder="НОМЕР ТЕЛЕФОНА" class="text-center tel"></p>
                    <p><button type="submit" class="submit">ЗАПИСАТСЯ</button></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $('button.submit').on('click', function(){
          var dateCL = $('input.dateCL').val();
          var timeCL = $('input.timeCL').val();
          var name = $('input.name').val();
          var tel = $('input.tel').val();
          $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: "component/send.php",
            data: { dateCL: dateCL, timeCL: timeCL, name: name, tel: tel }
          })
            .done(function( msg ) {
              alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
            });
        })
      })
    </script>
```

**код из send.php**

```
$data = [
    "dateCL" => $_POST["dateCL"],
    "timeCL" => $_POST["timeCL"],
    "name" => $_POST["bame"],
    "tel" => $_POST["tel"],
];
$connection = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=jonny', 'root', '');
$sql = 'INSERT INTO waiting (dateCL, timeCL, name, tel) VALUES (:dateCL, :timeCL, :name, :tel)';
$statement = $connection->prepare($sql);
$result = $statement->execute($data);
var_dump($data);
```

Comment: это `var_dump` в последней строке выдает

Comment: После того, как я убрал var_dump, ошибки исчезла, но при этом данные все равно не приходят в базу данных

Comment: ключи в `$data` начинайте с `:` -> `:dateCL`.

Comment: в конструктор PDO передайте 4м параметром `[PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION]` чтобы он вам исключения выбрасывал при ошибках, раз вы их не проверяете никак

Comment: Всем спасибо, решил проблему

Comment: оформил ответом

Answer (score 1, accepted):

указанное сообщение это не ошибка а вывод `var_dump` в конце кода. Ошибок вы никаких не получаете, поскольку PDO по умолчанию не использует исключения. Если вы проверите результат возврата `execute()`, то там будет `false`.

Чтобы PDO выкидывал исключение при ошибке, передайте 4м параметром вызова конструктора массив `[PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION]`.

Параметры в `prepare()` передаюется в виде `[':param' => $value]` с двоеточием у имени плейсхолдера (зачем не знаю, но так).

скорее всего указанные изменения либо решат проблему, либо по крайней мере покажут ошибку.

Что касается клиентской части, то логичнее поля идентифицировать не классом, а по ID. в итоге клиентской код для отправки запросам можно упросить до

```
$("#send").click(function(){
     let data = {
          dateCL: $("#dateCL").val(),
          ....
        } ;

     $.post("/path/to/script", data, function(result){
          console.log(result);
     });
});
```

URL для отправки лучше всегда начинать с корня